# Three JS move axis location of group

Tags: three.js

I have a planeGeo in a group with a few other things, and I would like to move the axis point of that group to a different spot other than center.

I tried doing it with `translateOnAxis`, but that just moves the group.

Is it possible to ONLY move the axis point of a group, and not have it translate it's position?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37779104/how-can-i-rotate-around-the-center-of-a-group-in-three-js

Comment: @WestLangley Not sure how it's a dupe when that one specifically asks how to rotate around center, when this question specifically asks how NOT to.

Comment: @WestLangley Actually, you're right! Same concept, different solution!