# ThreeJS translate center of Object3D to it's actual center

Tags: three.js

I have an `Object3D` containting multiple Cubes which represent a grid. However when I move my camera (`OrbitControls`) the view dosn't rotate around the center of my grid but rather the center of my initial view.

```js
function createGrid(x, y) {

    const field = new THREE.Object3D()

    for(let col = 0; col < x; col++){
        for (let row = 0; row < y; row++) {
            let cube = createCube()
            cube.position.x = col 
            cube.position.z = row

            field.add(cube)
        }
    }

    return field
}
```

The `createCube()` function creats a simple cube (size 1 for all dimensions) and sets some default values (Material, Color). `filed` is then appended to the scene via `scene.add(createGrid(10, 10))`.

Now, how can I translate my "center" to the actual center of the `Object3D` element?

I'm new to Three.js and WebGL in general. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I rotate around the center of a group in Three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37779104/how-can-i-rotate-around-the-center-of-a-group-in-three-js)

Comment: That seems like a solution for me. Thanks.